# Equivalent to layout_weight for height

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

Is there any equivalent command to the mentioned Iayout-weight to dynamically define the height of more than one View inside a LinearLayout? I want to have a LinearLayout with orientation="vertical" and then split that height to a defined ratio, but I can't find any command for that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need an equivalent to `layout-weight`, you just use that.  Set your width to a value you want, set height to be 0dp and set the weight to be in proportion to what you want.

Comment: in my case the buttons go invisible if height is set to 0dp, I am using a linearlayout vertical orientation.

Answer (score 4):

whenever you use `layout-weight`. if you give width as `0dp` then it weight is applicable for width. like that for height also